# How can I a number to CPF format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, formatting, currency, number-formatting

I would like to format an integer to the CPF (Cadastro de Pessoas Físicas)(Brazilian ID Number) format.
I would like a function that takes an integer of 11 digits as an argument and returns a string formatted like this:

```
###.###.###-##
```

Example:

```
formatToCPF(integer){     // integer=94256116885

    String formattedString

    //code

return formattedString    //returns "942.561.168-85"
```

Comment: What have you attempted yourself to solve your issue?

Comment: To have a succinct function to resolve this, look into `destructuring` and `template literals` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the String value of integer and then format it with slice().

```
s = integer.toString()
formattedString = s.slice(0,3)+"."+
    s.slice(3,6)+"."+
    s.slice(6,9)+"-"+
    s.slice(9,11)
```